# ExpendableCalendar is not expended on iOS, react native calendars

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-calendars

I have integrated ExpendableCalendar of [react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) and it's expended and close properly on android but not working on iOS. It's not scrolling up or down on iOs.
This is the code I have added::

```
<ExpandableCalendar
    testID={testIDs.expandableCalendar.CONTAINER}
    initialPosition={ExpandableCalendar.positions.OPEN}
    theme={{
        selectedDayTextColor: colors.grey,
        selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#d1e8ff',
    }}
    firstDay={1}
    markingType={'multi-dot'}
    markedDates={this.state.markedDates}
    leftArrowImageSource={require('./img/previous.png')}
    rightArrowImageSource={require('./img/next.png')}
    minDate={this.props.minDate ? this.props.minDate : ''}
    customKnob={true}
    renderCustomKnob={(isOpen) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.knobContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.knobStyle}>{isOpen ? 'Pull Up' : 'Pull Down'}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }}
/>
```

Please check once, and tell me what I am doing wrong here. This expended calendar feature is not working on iOS. It's working properly on android.